# What is ethical scoring?

Tags: basketball

JJ Redick called Devin Booker an *ethical* scorer. What does this mean?

https://twitter.com/scooperhoops/status/1654707471934537729

https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/comments/139cd24/highlight_jj_redick_on_devin_booker_he_might_be/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JJ Redick is referring to the fact that Booker was scoring without making trips to the free throw line. By "ethical" he meant, no flopping, no getting free throws which are considered easy points to pad the points scored statistics.

Based on the timing of the comment and Booker's recent performance prior to that comment made, I'm assuming JJ Redick was referring to Booker's performance in [Game 3](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202305050PHO.html) of the Western Conference semi Finals against the Denver Nuggets. Booker scored 47 points, only going to the foul line once, at the end of the game. Hence, he scored 40+ "ethically" without getting free throw points.